# When using + in grep command, why is it need to be escaped?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to find lines starting with several '=' symbols in a text file that looks like following.

```
Line one
And this is Line two
=======text in line three
Line four
=======text in line five
Line six
```

But when I use the command as:

```
grep '^=+'
```

It outputs nothing. But if use like:

```
grep '^=\+'
```

I can get the intended output. My question is why we need to escape the `+` symbol when we don't want to escape `*` symbol?. That means I can issue the following command and can get an output.

```
grep '^=*'
```

Whats the the different between `*` and `+` symbols? is `+` being treated as a special character within `grep` command?

Comment: `\+` is a quantifier matching 1 or more repetitions in BRE POSIX, `+` is a literal `+`. The `*` is a quantifier in both BRE and ERE POSIX, and if escaped, matches a literal `*`.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/293148/grep-operator-does-not-work

Comment: [google "regular expressions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expressions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `grep` parses the pattern as a [BRE (Basic Regular Expressions) POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) expression. That means, `\+` is parsed as a quantifier matching 1 or more repetitions, and `+` is parsed as a literal `+` symbol. In ERE POSIX, it is vice versa, `+` is a quantifier, and `\+` is a literal `+` symbol.  To use ERE POSIX syntax, use `grep -E 'pattern'`.

So, these are equal:

```
grep 'a\+'   # Finds 'aaaaa'
grep -E 'a+' # Finds 'aaaaa'

grep 'a+'   # Finds 'a+'
gre -E 'a\+' # Finds 'a+'
```

Note that `\+` is not always working across different `grep` implementations, and a usual workaround is repeating patterns with `*`, i.e. `a\+` => `aa*`.

The `*` is a quantifier matching 0 or more repetitions in both BRE and [ERE (Extended Regular Expressions) POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04), and if escaped, matches a literal `*` symbol.

Comment: Note that `\+` is the operator in BRE reflects that fact that it isn't strictly necessary, *because* you can always replace `a+` with `aa*`. ERE just recognizes that `+` is more often used as an operator than a literal character.